# How to hypothesis test in Bayesian ordinal regression with BRMS in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian

I'm trying to figure out if I'm expressing this model correctly, and whether or not I'm testing my hypotheses correctly.

I ran a study where I had people classify stimuli with two  dimensions. Then I showed them some examples of those stimuli asked them to rate how typical each stimulus was on a Likert scale from 1 to 7. I asked each participant to rate 36 stimuli. Each stimuli had a relevant dimension and an incidental dimension. Each dimension was set to either an *extreme* value, a *marginal* value, or a *modal* value. (Each dimension was bimodal with a trough at the category boundary. These labels are actually just a classification of a continuous dimension from 1 to 100, though the bimodal distribution was symmetrical and the research question concerns the modes rather than any particular value. Extreme values are tails, marginal values are the tails of the bimodals nearest the trough, and modes are modes. During the training phase the dimensions are uncorrelated.)

I've come to realize that a cumulative ordered logistic regression is probably the best way to analyze this data. Using the `brms` package in R, I've specified my model using dummy coding for the relevant and incidental feature values, setting the reference categories for both to the modes. (I've tried a model with interactions wherein the system dummy codes as it sees fit from my categorical parameters, and the interaction didn't seem to matter.)

```
rating_dummy1 <- brm(rating ~ labRel_Marginal + labRel_Extreme + labInc_Marginal + labInc_Extreme + (labRel_Marginal + labRel_Extreme + labInc_Marginal + labInc_Extreme | uniqueid), data = testing.rfc, family = cumulative)
```

Note: I'm 99% sure this is the same as `rating_fit1.1 <- brm(rating ~ label_relevant + label_incidental + (label_relevant + label_incidental | uniqueid), data = testing.rfc, family = cumulative)`, once the reference category for those factors is releveled to `mode`.

My main research questions are:

1. Do people rate stimuli with relevant modal values more highly than other stimuli?
2. Do people rate stimuli with incidental modal values more highly than other stimuli?

**My main questions: Does this model specification make sense, and how do I test these research questions?**

I've attempted to test them by asking "are stimuli with other labels any different than modal ones?

```
(hypothesis(rating_dummy1, c("labRel_Marginal = 0",
                         "labRel_Extreme = 0",
                         "labInc_Marginal = 0",
                         "labInc_Extreme = 0"), alpha = .05, class = "b"))
```

Is there a more nuanced formulation I could make here? I'm struggling a bit with the interpretation and formulation of the hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you ask the question on brms-users (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/brms-users).